# Nodejs error after webpacking the bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have this original code from my node router.js:

```
import express from "express";
import passport from "passport";
import graphqlHTTP from "express-graphql";

import schema from "./graphql/schema";

import * as authenticator from "./authenticator";

import db from "./models";

const router = express(router);

export const set = app => {

    app.use(
        "/graphql",
        graphqlHTTP({
            schema: schema,
            graphiql: true,
            pretty: true,
            formatError: error => ({
                message: error.message,
                locations: error.locations,
                stack: error.stack,
                path: error.path
            })
        })
    );
};
```

It runs fine on my development enviromnet, but when I build the bundle using webpack and move to production, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ node server.js
---> /Volumes/workspace/dev
---> /Volumes/workspace/dev/data/aeirtudb.bin
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators ../node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13

/Volumes/workspace/dev/bundle/webpack:/routes.js:23
const router = express(router);
^
ReferenceError: Ne is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (/Volumes/workspace/dev/bundle/webpack:/routes.js:23:1)
    at r (/Volumes/workspace/dev/bundle/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at /Volumes/workspace/dev/bundle/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/workspace/dev/bundle/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

I have no idea of what's going on here... Where is that "Ne " is coming from?

My webpack builder configuration

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

var nodeModules = {};
fs
  .readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(function(x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  entry: "./server.js",
  target: "node",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../bundle"),
    filename: "server.js"
  },
  externals: nodeModules,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
      raw: true,
      entryOnly: false
    })
  ],
  devtool: "sourcemap",
  mode: "production"
};
```

Comment: `router` is not defined on this line `const router = express(router);`

Is there any chance that it should be `const router = express.Router()`?
[express v4 docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router)